# How to correctly manage an Arraylist

Tags: arrays, class, arraylist

I would like to ask for advice on how to write a program in Java for managing a list of people.

Each person has 4 parameters that the user enters into the console. I need to store this data (hopefully I guess correctly) in an Arraylist.
Furthermore, I need to list all the entered records.
And I need also be able to search in these records (according to the entered dat, find a specific person).

I am not sure whether each parameter must be stored in a specific Arraylist (ie whether there will be 4 Arraylists in total).

And ideally how many classes should I create in such a program for clarity.